# How to link data from Excel 2010 spreadsheets into my workbook by one constant

Tags: excel

I need to connect data from spreadsheets sent by others to my main Excel 2010 workbook.  The data sent can't be copied and pasted directly... example: I have tabs for every 9th, 10th, 11th, and 12th grade student (each a separate tab).  Teachers send spreadsheets weekly with scores/grades that are not of every 9th grade student or are mixed with various classes.  No matter how I format their info, it will not directly match my workbook tabs.  How can I link the data to go directly to the correct student and not type thousands of scores/grades in weekly?
Yes, I am new to all of this.

Comment: are the submitted sheets all formatted consistently? There are several ways to accomplish, need to see examples to help.

Comment: Can you explain why the tabs would not be the same as the names on the sheets? Just saying they don't match is not enough info.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Let's use the 9th grade tab. My workbook lists every student classified as a 9th grader- 270 students.  We have many teachers per grade level, with mixed classes. Ex. if one Alg 1 teacher sends me data which contains student name and score, these students may be in 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th grades... sometimes students are absent, all students don't finish and will not be in the spreadsheet, etc.   They are literally different every time due to these issues. I have to add the scores for these students into my workbook... the commonality is the student's names.

Comment: Well "pnuts" there is no avoiding as these are directives and I have no choice; therefore, solutions are needed.  You mentioned many tools, all of which I am researching and not finding what I need.  Specifics would be helpful.